# Jflex Unexpected Character error

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, jflex

I started studying jflex. When i try to generate output using jflex for the following code I keep getting an error

```
Error in file "\abc.flex" (line 29): 
Unexpected character

[ \t\n]+                ;
^
1 error, 0 warnings.

Generation aborted.
```

Code trying to run

```
letter   [a-zA-Z]
digit    [0-9]
intlit      [0-9]+
%{
#include <stdio.h>   
# define BASTYPTOK 257   /*following are output from yacc*/
# define IDTOK 258       /*yacc assigns token numbers */
# define LITTOK 259
# define CINTOK 260
# define INSTREAMTOK 261
# define COUTTOK 262
# define OUTSTREAMTOK 263
# define WHILETOK 264
# define IFTOK 265
# define ADDOPTOK 266
# define MULOPTOK 267
# define RELOPTOK 268
# define NOTTOK 269
# define STRLITTOK 270

main()  /*this replaces the main in the lex library*\
{  int  p;
    while (p= yylex())
              printf("%d is \"%s\"\n", p, yytext);
              /*yytext is where lex stores the lexeme*/}
%}

%%
[ \t\n]+                ;
"//".*"\n"              ;
{intlit}                {return(LITTOK);}
cin                     {return(CINTOK);}
"<<"                    {return(INSTREAMTOK);}
\<|"=="                 {return(RELOPTOK);}
\+|\-|"||"              {return(ADDOPTOK);}
"="                     {return(yytext[0]);}
"("                     {return(yytext[0]);}
")"                     {return(yytext[0]);}
.                       {return (yytext[0]); /*default action*/}

%%
```

Can someone please help me figure out, what is causing the issue.
The pattern is also unindented properly.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That's valid `flex` input but it's not valid `jflex`. Since the included code is in `C` rather than `Java`, it's not clear to me why you would want to use `jflex`, but if your intent is to port the scanner to `Java` you might want to read the [JFlex manual section on porting.](http://jflex.de/manual.html#Porting)

In particular, the sections in `JFlex` input are quite different from `flex`:

```
        flex                                 JFlex

definitions and declarations            user code
%%                                      %%
rules                                   declarations
%%                                      %%
user code                               definitions and rules
```

So your definitions and rules are in the correct section for a `flex` file, but not for a `JFlex` file. (`JFlex` just copies the first section to the output, so it doesn't recognize the various syntax errors resulting from putting flex declarations where JFlex expects valid user code.)

Also, `JFlex` definitions are of the form `name = pattern` rather than `name pattern`, so once you get the order of the file sorted out, you'll also need to add the equals signs. And. of course, rewrite the `C` code in `Java`.